# Why is my function in React being called twice but not equaly executed?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

This is my function in my home.js React App, with all the needed logs:

```
function pin(){
  console.log('function pin()');
  var result = []
  var url = "http://warm-hamlet-63390.herokuapp.com/pin/list"
  axios.get(url)
  .then((res)=>{
    console.log('after .then');
    if(res.data){
      console.log('inside pin() if');
      for(var i in res.data.data)
      {
          result.push([i, res.data.data[i]])
      }
    }
    console.log('after pin() if');
  })
  console.log('end of pin()');
  return result;
}
```

Immediately after the function, I have my exported function that renders the page:

```
export default function App(){
  const{isLoaded, loadError} = useLoadScript({
    googleMapsApiKey: "my_api_key",
    libraries,
  })

  const [markers, setMarkers] = React.useState([]);
  if(loadError) return "Erro a carregar o mapa"
  if(!isLoaded) return "Carregando"

  return <div>
    {pin()}
    <GoogleMap 
    mapContainerStyle={mapContainerStyle} 
    zoom={11} 
    center={center}
    >
    <Marker
      position={
        {
           lat: 2, 
           lng:2
        }
      }
      icon={nivelpin.verde}
    >
    </Marker>

    </GoogleMap>
    
  </div>
}
```

The JSON file that the URL is being set to has 7 records in it, but as you can see in the image, it's being executd twice.

The function is only executing twice inside the `.then((res)=>{`

Why is that? Is it something to do with axios?

Image: https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/656598463638798357/852982191029747732/unknown.png

EDIT: Added the logs and the function App() + Image that shows the logs:

https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/656598463638798357/852995551691276368/unknown.png

Comment: Can you show the whole code, It is not sure how you are executing this

Comment: It's *probably* something to do with rendering the React components, rather than anything to do with Axios.  You could easily test this by putting more logging statements in the function.  But the code shown doesn't demonstrate how the function is executed at all, let alone twice.

Comment: you are both right, i forgot a crucial part of the question x) It's edited now

Comment: @Enguias: How have you confirmed that it's only executing the `.then()` callback twice and not executing `pin()` twice?  How is this related to React?

Comment: I used console.log() and putted it in almost every line of the function. It only repeated the logs after the  ```.then((res)=>{```

Comment: @Enguias post the whole component. There is not enough info in your question to determine the cause of the issue you are experiencing. I doubt it's the only the `then()` getting called twice, check the Network tab in Dev Tools to confirm. David is probably right, it's a re-render triggering the second call.

Comment: @Enguias: The best thing to do now would be to replicate this in a live example, either here in a code snippet or on something like a CodeSandbox.  Then we can observe the behavior you're observing.

Comment: I edited my question, even the tittle, I added more logs, that show an interesting result, and posted the rest of the home.js. I will try what David said too.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling a function in the template that is returned. Meaning that function is going to get called on every render.

You have to store the results to a variable which gets rendered in your component. Something like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { data: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=10`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => this.setState({ data: json }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.state.data.map(el => (
            <li>
              {el.name}: {el.price_usd}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

([source](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/await-react/))

OR if you want to stick with a functional component:

```
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({ hits: [] });
 
  useEffect(async () => {
    const result = await axios(
      'https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=redux',
    );
 
    setData(result.data);
  });
 
  return (
    <ul>
      {data.hits.map(item => (
        <li key={item.objectID}>
          <a href={item.url}>{item.title}</a>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
 
export default App;
```

([source](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data))

Comment: @enguias please mark this answer correct when you are able so that it might help someone else with a similar issue.